# Why are my results in SSRS different from SQL SMS?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I've never seen this happen before, so I'm curious if anybody knows why, and maybe how I can correct for it.

This particular part of my code:

```
SELECT inv_num, co_line, 
    STUFF((
      SELECT '/' + rs2.inv_pro_description
      FROM @ReportSet rs2
      WHERE rs2.inv_num = rs.inv_num AND
        rs2.co_line = rs.co_line
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as ipd_combo
FROM @ReportSet rs
WHERE inv_pro_seq IS NOT NULL AND inv_pro_description <> 'Less Previously Invoiced'
GROUP BY inv_num, co_line
```

results in a correct concatenation of my two results, e.g., "10% Advance/Fixed $5 Required" in this case. However, when utilizing this procedure in SSRS, my field contains instead "Fixed $5 Required/10% Advance".

I have grown accustomed to being able to predict my SSRS reports based on running SQL queries, so this confused me.

I don't really understand the STUFF / XML PATH code, of course. I've copied it from somebody else (on this website, naturally) so I know that might have something to do with it.

Comment: I found out, quite by accident, that if I replace the '/' in the above code with ' / ' that it will work correctly. (SQL SMS unchanged). The original code had a ',' instead, and this produced the same issue as the '/'. So...something about adding those spaces made SSRS start working?

Comment: ...and now it's not working...again. Nothing different in the code from before, same data, etc.

Comment: Try adding some `order by` criteria?

Comment: ...and now it's working...again. And now, not. All I'm doing is trying different orders of running the query in SQL SMS and pulling the data from a report. It seems random, but I know that's impossible.

Comment: Can you run a SQL Profiler trace and confirm what SQL is being sent to the server when you run the SSRS report?  And then compare that to your SSMS query?

Comment: Brilliant, APH. That seems to work every time, now. I just added the line "ORDER BY rs2.inv_pro_seq" before the "FOR XML...".

Comment: Peter, that's over my head at the moment. But I appreciate the comment, and I will look into that as part of my ongoing education.

Comment: Glad it helped, @DaveX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get consistent ordering, add an `order by` clause to your inner select:

```
SELECT inv_num, co_line, 
    STUFF((
      SELECT '/' + rs2.inv_pro_description
      FROM @ReportSet rs2
      WHERE rs2.inv_num = rs.inv_num AND
        rs2.co_line = rs.co_line
      ORDER BY rs2.inv_pro_seq --********
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as ipd_combo
FROM @ReportSet rs
WHERE inv_pro_seq IS NOT NULL AND inv_pro_description <> 'Less Previously Invoiced'
GROUP BY inv_num, co_line
```

The commented asterisks indicate the added line.

(I answered in comments, but adding this here for consistency/permanency).

Comment: This is a good reminder for me to always worry about ORDER. It looks random the way that data is stored, even though I do know there is some underlying reason for it, so ordering it is a good idea even if it doesn't seem like it needs it.